# Why logo is not going to the left side completely

Tags: html, css-float

When I try to float my logo to the left using `float:left` attribute, it does not go to the left completely, rather it keeps some margin in both top and left side, but I have already set the margin and padding to 0 for all elements in my web page.

Comment: Provide the code part you have done so far

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you are asking. And be **sure** that there is no answers for your question in this site or with tiny search on Google.

Answer (score -1):

you will use "flex-box" to parent.

Answer (score -2):

Browsers add 8px of default margin to body. So if you are not resetting the browser styles you will get that margin. If possible please share the code.

Comment: The OP said they had set the margin and padding of **all** elements (which would include the body) to 0.